# Obtener datos en Firebase y crear un objeto con ellos, Flutter, Dart

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Me gustaría crear un objeto usando los datos obtenidos en mi base de datos de Firebase. Obtengo los datos correctamente pero no puedo crear dicho objeto de la manera en la que lo estoy intentado. No se por qué no funciona, es mi primera vez usando Dart.

Aquí mi código. El objetivo es devolver un objeto "vacío" si el documento de mi base de datos no existe o devolver un objeto correcto si el documento existe. Cuando hago `print(value['id']` dentro del `.then()`, obtengo el id del documento que busco, pero cuando creo el nuevo objeto, no funciona.

```
MaterialQR selectFromFirebase(String document) {
    MaterialQR res = MaterialQR(exercises: [], image: '', name: '', id: '');
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('MaterialQR')
        .doc(document).get()
        .then((value) => res = new MaterialQR(
        exercises: value['exercises'],
        image: value['image'],
        name: value['name'],
        id: value['id']));
    return res;
  }
```

Agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda o consejo, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un Future, por lo tanto necesitas esperar a que termine la respuesta de `Firestore` para devolver la información.

Tu método quedaría así :

```dart
Future<MaterialQR> selectFromFirebase(String document) async {
    MaterialQR res = MaterialQR(exercises: [], image: '', name: '', id: '');
    final data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('MaterialQR').doc(document).get();
        
    if(data != null) {
      return MaterialQR(
        exercises: data['exercises'],
        image: data['image'],
        name: data['name'],
        id: data['id']));
    } 
    return res;
  }
```

Si estás usando widgets,  podrías invocarlo con un `FutureBuilder` o sino simplemente con un `await` y `async`.

Comment: Como bien dices, la invocación sería algo así: ```MaterialQR material = await selectFromFirebase('string');```? Muchas gracias por la respuesta, me ayuda mucho!

Comment: sí, no te olvides de que si usas `await` necesitas agregar la palabra reservada `async` al costado del método;    void tu metodo() async {

Comment: @StyleMain si te sirvió la respuesta puedes marcarla como resuelta :)